# Rounding "string number" with decimal comma

Tags: java

What is the best way to round a string number with a decimal comma and keep it as a string?

Do I have to convert the string to a double, then round it to the nearest integer and then convert it back to a string?

For example, "21,55" should be rounded to "22".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
String s = "21,55";
s = s.replace(',', '.');
s = Long.toString(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s)));
```

First replace the `,` with a `.`

Then convert the `String` to `Double` and then round the value. Since `Math.round(Double)` will return a `long`, you need to convert it to `String`.

Comment: As the OP says, "round it to the nearest integer". Neither `ceil` nor `floor` does that.

Comment: This works well with decimal dot numbers, but my numbers are with decimal comma. I did write "21.55" in my example, it should have been "21,55", sorry!

Comment: @SnakeJuice I updated my answer according to your edit. You need to replace the comma with a dot first.

Comment: @Atri Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor` rounds it to lower integer value
and `Math.ceil` rounds it up to higer integer value use `math.round` in your case

```
Long.toString(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(strNum)));
```

Comment: As the OP says, "round it to the nearest integer". Neither `ceil` nor `floor` does that.